# Subset sublist by row

Tags: r, subset, apply

I have a list of lists like so

```
ls = list()
elem1=list()
elem2=list()
elem3=list()
elem1$vect1 = c(1.1,1.2,1.3)

elem2$vect1 = c(2.1,2.2,2.3)
elem2$vect2 = c(3.1,3.2,3.3)

elem3$vect1 = c(4.1,4.2,4.3)
elem3$vect2 = c(5.1,5.2,5.3)
elem3$vect3 = c(6.1,6.2,6.3)

ls[[1]] = elem1
ls[[2]] = elem2
ls[[3]] = elem3
```

The list continues with a lot more elements. Every sublist has a variable number of vectors, all of length 3. The whole structure can be thought as a list of matrices with indexes *i (variable)* and *j (1,2,3)*.

First I want to extract the rows with a given index *i*. So for example for *i=2* I would like to have something like

```
elem2
3.1 3.2 3.3

elem3
5.1 5.2 5.3
```

Then I also want to extract the single elements inside the rows, so that for *j=2*

```
elem2
3.2

elem3
5.2
```

I guess the most concise way of doing that would be with an `*apply`, but I could not figure out which one and how.

Comment: `lapply(ls, function(x) unlist(x[2])); lapply(ls, function(x) unlist(x[2])[2])`

Comment: OK, it works as expected. The only thing is I am unable to use the output. In the sense that I end up with a list while I would like to store the values (say 3.2 and 5.2 in this case) inside an array.

Comment: casting with `as.numeric` did the trick. If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it.